# Sum a list of numbers until a number 0 is found

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a data list like the following `data = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]` and I want to add up the elements of the list to be like this:
`[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0]`, where the previous element is the value 0 and the last element other than 0 is the result of the value of the previous number of elements.

I've tried with the following code, if I do the trace, it looks like it can be done, but when I run it it doesn't show results but it's still in the loop that doesn't stop.

I tried it with :

```
data = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
k = len(data)-1
while True:
    print(k)
    if(data[k-1] == 0):
        continue
    elif(data[k] == 0):
        print("h")
        continue
    elif(data[k-1] != 0):
        data[k] = data[k] + data[k-1]
        data[k-1] = 0
    k = k-1
    if(k == 0):
        break
print(data)
```

Comment: How is `k` supposed to become 0 if `continue` is executed?

Comment: If either of the `continue` statements is executed, `k` will not change, and you will have an infinite loop with `k` remaining unchanged from then on.  Just delete the `continue` statements.  You're already using `elif`, so the `continue` statements aren't needed.  Also, you can replace the `while` loop with a `for` loop, which will handle `k` for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Iterate through the list and just add every time a non - zero number
  and append a zero to the list.
- when there is a 0 appearing just append the sum and make sum 0.
- if the last element is 0 add zero to the last number or the
  respective last number.
- Just remove the first zero and return the list.

.

```
data = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

def calc(data):
    sum = 0
    new = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i] == 0:
            new.append(sum)
            if i == len(data) - 1:
                new.append(0)
            sum = 0
        else:
            sum = sum = sum + data[i]
            new.append(0)
            if i == len(data) - 1:
                new.append(sum)
    if new[0] == 0:
        del new[0]
    return new
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple implementation. I think it is quite self-explanatory. You iterate over each item `n` in the list, if `n` is zero, you have two options a) if there is a previous sum `x`, append `x` and then `n` b) if there is no sum, just append 0.
If `n` is different from zero, sum it to `x`.

```
data = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

x = 0
r = []
for n in data:
    if n == 0:
        if x:
            r.append(x)
            x = 0
        r.append(n)
    else:
        x += n
        
print(r)
[1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the list and if current and next element are not 0 then add to a temp variable and put current element as 0, when the next element is zero put the value in the current element. Since, code checks for the next element with the current element, Iterate through 2nd last element and check for the last separately.

```
def arrange_list(arr):
    value = 0
    for x in range(len(arr)-1):
        if arr[x] != 0:
            value += arr[x]
        else:
            value = 0
        if arr[x+1] != 0:
            arr[x] = 0
        else:
            arr[x] = value
            value = 0
    if value !=0:
        arr[-1] = value + arr[-1]
    return arr
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mentioned in the Comments you get to an infinite loop because of all the continues. You need to make sure that the line k=k-1 happens to avoid infinite loop.

Second why do `while True` and then `if k==0: break` change it to `while k>=0`.

Anyway your code won't work because it will have a problem with elements that follow a zero.

This code will work:

```
ans = []
tmp = 0
data = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
for curr in data:
    if curr != 0:
        tmp += curr
    elif tmp == 0:
        ans.append(tmp)
    else:
        ans.append(tmp)
        ans.append(0)
        tmp = 0
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to start the value of k from 1 and set `elif(data[k] != 0):`. However, it will modify your original list.

```
data=[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
k = 1
while True:
    
    if(data[k-1] == 0):
        pass
    elif(data[k] == 0):
        pass
    elif(data[k] != 0):
        data[k] = data[k] + data[k-1]
        print(data[k])
        data[k-1] = 0
    k = k+1
    if(k == len(data)):
        break
print(data)
```

Output

```
3
5
6
2
3
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

- Here your code is running to infinite loop as you are using continue
  statement which will again start the loop from beginning.
- As in your case data[k] is zero so the first elif statement is always true
  and the continue statement is executing.
- Because of the above reason the code k=k-1 line is always unreachable and k value is always 7 in your case. So the while loop is running infinitely.

Below is a suggested code sample which satisfies your use case.

```
data = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
k = len(data)-1
for i in range(0,k):
    if(data[i]==0):
        continue
    if(data[i]!=0 and data[i+1]!=0):
        data[i+1]=data[i]+data[i+1]
        data[i]=0
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this:

```
def convert(A):
    B = [0] * len(A)
    partial_sum = 0
    for i in range(len(A) - 1):
        partial_sum += A[i]
        if A[i + 1] == 0:
            B[i] = partial_sum
            partial_sum = 0
            
    if A[-1] != 0:
        B[-1] = partial_sum + A[-1]
        
    return B
```

As opposed to the previous answer, this actually preserves the length of the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a **general reusable** method which comes in hand in some cases.

Here it is, it returns a generator:

```
def slice_when(predicate, iterable):
    i, x, size = 0, 0, len(iterable)
    while i < size-1:
        if predicate(iterable[i], iterable[i+1]):
            yield iterable[x:i+1]
            x = i + 1
        i += 1
    yield iterable[x:size]
```

---

### Example of usage

Once you have in place this method, you can use it in this way:

```
data = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

test_method = slice_when(lambda _, y: y==0, data)
list(test_method)
#=> [[1], [0], [0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 3, 1], [0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [0]]
```

---

### Your case

This is how to apply it for solving your point:

```
res = []
for e in slice_when(lambda _, y: y==0, data):
    res += [0]*(len(e)-1) + [sum(e)]
    
res
#=> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0]
```